# Converting an Oracle merge query into mysql mySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

```
    MERGE INTO PAGEEDITCONTROL A
      USING (SELECT
              '1585' AS PAGEID
       ,'admin' AS EDITUSER
       ,sysdate AS EDITDATE
          FROM DUAL) B
      ON (A.PAGEID = B.PAGEID)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET
      A.EDITUSER = B.EDITUSER
     ,A.EDITDATE = B.EDITDATE
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT  (
      A.PAGEID
     ,A.EDITUSER
     ,A.EDITDATE
      )VALUES(
      B.PAGEID
     ,B.EDITUSER
     ,B.EDITDATE
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO  
pageeditcontrol (pageid, edituser, editdate) 
VALUES  ('1585', 'admin', sysdate()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
edituser = values(edituser), 
editdate = values(editdate);
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/548570/1563700 this does a delete and then an insert. The delete may be cascaded to foreign keys and delete triggers may be executed. This could modify your database in a way you are not expecting it

Comment: @mklemenz The delete and insert talked about in the answer pertains to the REPLACE statement not the INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a similar construct which looks less like an upsert, but more like an insate: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (see the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).